# Image auto swapping script doesnt show image most of the time?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script running to rotate between two of my logos.
What i am trying to do is the page will load and then the image will begin to rotate directly to the other image with out blank.

Here is the code:

```js
var logo1 = "logo2.png";
var logo2 = "logo1.png";
var images = new Array (logo1, logo2);
var index = 1;

function rotateImage()
{
  $('.logoimage').fadeOut('slow', function()
  {
    $(this).attr('src', images[index]);

    $(this).fadeIn('fast', function()
    {
      if (index == images.length-1)
      {
        index = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        index++;
      }
    });
  });
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
  setInterval (rotateImage, 5000);
});
```

```html
<img class="logoimage" src="logo1.png" onmouseover="this.src='logo2.png'" onmouseout="this.src='logo1.png'" alt="Dear Leader" style="display: inline;">
```

Comment: Why have two logos? The whole point of a logo is to have just the one of them

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Well while looking at the script working the src is changing thats great BUT the logo images doesnt always change it just blinks once. Is there a way to preload these images into the variable? I believe it could be realted to having to redraw them all the time using the script?

Answer (score 0):

Instead to use onmouseover and onmouseout you can use the jQuery [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/).

While you are in the hovering function you have to stop the timer fading effects, in order to avoid the blinking effect.

My proposal is:

```js
var logo1 = "https://ac3d197e9505f18c50e0-32b9f49f48b2c22be12b40ee79e2acc4.ssl.cf1.rackcdn.com/icon/logos_and_badges_thumbs_up/7x5uDqD4GBTrCSbXggZ-/58C79CAE-C3E6-4D6A-BAF5-A03631274FD7.png";
var logo2 = "https://www.facebookbrand.com/img/assets/asset.f.logo.lg.png";
var images = new Array (logo1, logo2);
var index = 1;
var onHovering = false;

function rotateImage() {
  if (onHovering) {
    return; // prevent fading while hovering...
  }
  
  $('.logoimage').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', images[index]);
    $(this).fadeIn('fast', function() {
      if (index == images.length-1) {
        index = 0;
      } else {
        index++;
      }
    });
  });
}


$(function () {
  setInterval (rotateImage, 1000);
  $('.logoimage').hover(function() {
    onHovering = true;
    $(this).attr('src', images[0]);
  }, function() {
    onHovering = false;
    $(this).attr('src', images[1]);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>

<img class="logoimage" src="https://www.facebookbrand.com/img/assets/asset.f.logo.lg.png"  alt="Dear Leader" style="display: inline;">
```